# How to remove files from "others" storage in Mac OS (Catalina)?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

So, I wanted to install Mac OS Big Sur on my device. But I am not able to do so because others is taking 54 gigabytes of storage from total of 128 gigabytes of my device. I've searched loads of sources on internet, but not found any solution. I've tried clearing cache, but it doesn't help the cause.

The only thing that I've installed on my device is 14 gigabytes of Apple's Xcode for my iOS app development.

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this problem? I don't want to uninstall my Xcode since it contains lots of projects.

[Screenshot 1: My Mac device configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXY4F.png)

[Screenshot 2: Here's the problem. Can't clear the storage from others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuxIm.png)

Comment: Click on Review Files by Reduce Clutter and then File Browser and review what you've got...

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer use and troubleshooting. [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a much better place to ask about this, but they already have [Q&As about this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) -- the short answer is you need a program that'll analyze the disk usage in more detail to find out what's actually using all that space.